# Discord.py TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello i dont know why this code isnt work:

````
class MusicPlayer():
    __slots__ = ("client", "_guild", "_ctxs", "_channel", "_cog", "np", "volume", "current", "colour", "task")
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    next = asyncio.Event()

    def __init__(self, ctx, client):

        self.client = client
        self._guild = ctx.guild
        self._ctxs = ctx
        self._channel = ctx.channel
        self._cog = ctx.cog

        self.np = None
        self.volume = defaultvolume
        self.current = None
        self.colour = self.client.defaultcolour

        ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

    async def player_loop(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()

        while True:
            self.next.clear()

            try:
                async with timeout(300):
                    self.current = await queue.get()
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                return
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                guild = self._guild
                vc = guild.voice_client
                self.destroy(guild)
                if not vc: return
                await self._ctxs.send(":point_right: **I disconnected myself from the **`{}`** voice channel as I was not playing audio for 5 minutes!**".format(vc.channel.name))
                return
            except:
                self.destroy(self._guild)
                await self._ctxs.send(":thumbsdown: **Error: getting next song failed!** Please retry later!")
                return

            self._ctxs.voice_client.play(self.current, after=lambda: self.client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(next.set))
            self.current.volume = self.volume
            thumbnail = self.current.thumbnail if self.current.thumbnail else self.client.user.avatar_url
            self.colour = await self.client.get_average_colour(thumbnail)
            embednps = discord.Embed(colour=self.colour)
            embednps.add_field(name="Now Playing", value=f"```{self.current.title}```", inline=False)
            embednps.add_field(name="Link", value=f"[URL]({self.current.web_url})", inline=True)
            embednps.add_field(name="Duration", value=self.client.time_from_seconds(self.current.duration), inline=True)
            embednps.add_field(name="Channel", value=f"{self.current.uploader}", inline=False)
            embednps.set_thumbnail(url=f"{thumbnail}")
            embednps.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {self.current.requester}", icon_url=self.current.requester.avatar_url)
            self.np = await self._channel.send(embed=embednps)

            await next.wait()
            print("Terminated")

            # Cleanup player
            self.current.cleanup()
            self.current = None

    async def add_song(self, player):
        return await self.queue.put(player)

    def destroy(self, guild):
        return self.client.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))



@bot.command(aliases=['yt', 'youtube'])
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if url is None:
        await ctx.send("Music: Please specify a Youtube URL. Syntax (!play {URL})")
        return

    if ctx.guild.voice_client is None:
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("Music: Please join a Voice Channel or use join command.")
            return
        await channel.connect()
    else:
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("Music: Please join a Voice Channel or use join command.")
            return
        if ctx.guild.voice_client.channel != ctx.message.author.voice.channel:
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.move_to(channel)

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=ctx.bot.loop, stream=True)

        if ctx.guild.voice_client.is_playing():
            await MusicPlayer.add_song(MusicPlayer, player)
            await ctx.send('Music: {} has now been added to the Queue'.format(player.title))
            return

        voice_channel = ctx.guild.voice_client
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(MusicPlayer.next.set))
        await ctx.send('Music: Now playing {}'.format(player.title))
````

Who can explain why its isnt work? Console says me that error:

```
self.after(error)
TypeError: <lambda () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Can you provide additional information regarding where in the code the error occurs? I'm having a hard time matching the error to the code.

Comment: Im think its somewhere here: voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(MusicPlayer.next.set))

Comment: First music playing but queue doesnt work - after first music ends its says that type error

Comment: Not sure if this will work or not but the only solution I have looking at your code is to change `voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(MusicPlayer.next.set))` to `voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(next.set))` as that was used above in your code apparently successfully.

Comment: same thing, console says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 611, in _call_after
    self.after(error)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: after first music ends (next music isnt starting playing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have `lambda: ...` this is a function that takes no arguments, the error you are getting implies that what ever is calling it passes it an argument, sometimes callbacks pass an event object which you want to ignore, so usually the solution is to do something like:

```
lambda x=None: ...
```

this way it can take 1 or 0 arguments and you don't need to use `x`.

Comment: Okay, thanks that helped me to delete that error, i changed to voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda x=None: ctx.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(MusicPlayer.next.set)) but now my next song doesnt work, dont say any error

Comment: ok but idk how to even help with that, have you gone through debugging like adding print statements and ensure they get run when you expect them to?